# NSButton not displaying alt image when disabled

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I recently noticed that my app, when running on recent OSes (>10.10 I think) was not displaying button images correctly.

Seems that any time a button was set to disabled, the button drew as a solid grey block instead of the Alt Image which certainly used to draw fine.

I see a few mentions of this on the inter webs but never an answer. Is this an known issue with recent Mac OS?

Comment: which ver of Xcode are you using. Why do u have to guess your OS version ? U can easily check it :(

Comment: guessing when the change occurred. I have since noticed there is one button mode (switch) which does show the alt image when disabled, but it means redesigning the way the button is used. Not really a solution but a workaround